# How to draw a different shade of a given color with each iteration

Tags: java

I have a grid where each cell of the grid has `sarin` parameter. This parameter represents an amount of sarin in the grid. One cell is the source of the `sarin` and other cells have the value of this parameter dependent on the distance from the initial cell (closer to it means higher sarin amount).

What I want to do now is to color the cells dependent on the amount of sarin. The highest value will be fully red (255,0,0). Then with every increase of 10 the shade of the red will be a little darker. This is how the for cycle should look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sarin; i=i+10){ //with every change of 10
    rectangle.setFillColor(color);
    // here change the color to a bit darker red
}
```

How to change the shade of red in the cycle?

Comment: which Rectangle and color do you use (look import), awt, javafx ? share more code, with the grid, ..

Comment: Assuming `color` is `java.awt.Color` there's a constructor that takes the int values for the individual channels. Thus just create a new color for each shade ( `new Color(shadeOfRed, 0, 0)`). Ideally you'd create an array of shades and do a lookup based on the sarin value.

Comment: @azro I am using Anylogic software for modelling which uses `java.awtColor` I believe